# How to make an initial commit using pygit2?

Tags: python, git, pygit2

Using the [pygit2](https://www.pygit2.org) package how do you create an initial commit on a new repository?

I keep getting an error message that "refs/heads/master" isn't found.

Comment: Why would this be different from creating any other commit?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Don't know. Just posting in case it helps someone else in the future. I've never used `pygit2` only done, e.g., `git init && git add . && git commit -am "Initial commit"`. I kept getting an error message that "refs/heads/master" wasn't found and this was my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some context I'm working on a Python module created from the current spaghetti code I use to manage a GitLab instance to post and grade assignments for a university course. Work can be found [here](https://github.com/connorfuhrman/GitLab-Course-Manager/tree/main). My application requires that I download a repository as a "template" assignment to post for all students so I need to use the same file tree with a new git repository for all students in my course (hence the need to create initial commits over and over again).

The trick here, which I could not find documented anywhere (pygit2's documentation seems to be lacking as of this posting), is to set the first argument to [`create_commit`](https://www.pygit2.org/objects.html?highlight=create_commit) to `"HEAD"` rather than, e.g., `"refs/heads/master"` as in the example. Perhaps this is obvious to the git wizards out there but it took me a second to realize.

```py
import pygit2 as git

template_proj_location = "/file/path/to/the/template"
# 'proj' is a python-gitlab object for the GitLab project this repo needs to get pushed to

repo = git.init_repository(template_proj_location, initial_head='master', origin = proj.ssh_url_to_repo)
(index := repo.index).add_all()
index.write()
tree = index.write_tree()
me = git.Signature("My Name", "myemail@email.domain.edu")
repo.create_commit("HEAD", me, me, "commit msg", tree, [])

# Now to push the repo to the new location
_, ref = repo.resolve_refish(refish=repo.head.name)
remote = repo.remotes["origin"]
remote.push([ref.name], callbacks = my_func_to_get_RemoteCallbacks_obj_for_ssh_auth)
```

I used the following as references:

- https://gist.github.com/lig/dc1ede7e09488a62116fe90aa31617d9
- https://gist.github.com/metatoaster/6026706
- [Create, Clone, and Push to GitHub repo using PyGitHub and PyGit2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49458329/create-clone-and-push-to-github-repo-using-pygithub-and-pygit2)

Comment: If this is sub-optimal please chime in. I have approx. 3 hours experience with `pygit2` and am just posting here since I could not find mention of `"HEAD"` as above anywhere else.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Remote repo shows `master` branch as expected. I don't think it's in the detached HEAD state but [I don't know enough to dispute](https://imgur.com/YQi3ZFz). It got the job done for me